# Powershell - Excel formatting very slow

Tags: excel, powershell, datetime

I have an excel file in which I I have trouble converting time format from hh:mm AM/PM to hh:mm (24h). 
As the columns are formated in text, applying the number format property won't work at all (it simply does nothing).

However I've noticed that the formula "=TEXT(C1;"H:MM")" is working well.
So I built a powershell script that loops on each sheet and proceed to applying the formula in new columns in order to create the corrected values:

```
$rows = $WorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
for ($i = 8; $i -le $rows ; $i++)
{
    $formula1 = '=TEXTE(C'+$i+';"H:MM")'
    $formula2 = '=TEXTE(E'+$i+';"H:MM")'
    $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($i,4).Formula = $formula1
    $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($i,6).Formula = $formula2
}
```

Even though this loop makes the trick, it takes a huge time to execute.
My excel files contains about 37 sheets and about 100 rows per sheet. The whole process takes more than 20 minutes to finish.

What did I miss here, and how can I optimize it ?

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Comment: If I can get some yes, because for now my algorythm is still painfully slow

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the latest Powershell (v5) as each update did improve speed.  ~3,700 rows isn't a lot and Powershell can read data pretty fast.  Are there any other worksheets in here you aren't using?  Powershell must parse the entire document and if you have a huge amount of data, even unused, it will slow down processing tremendously.

Comment: Well no, appart from 2 additionnal useless small worksheets that I do not use, there is no other data. I'm indeed using the latest version of powershell. Maybe it is related to the latest office ?

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this which should speed up the process.  Of course, you have to loop through your sheets.

```
Sub DoThis()

    Sheet3.Range("M:M").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "h:mm;@"
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = Selection.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you did not read my post: First, I'm processing my file using powershell, not vba, then I just specified that number format property is not working as the cells are formatted as text. Please read before answering